# Get Dataframe out of value_counts calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have schools and classes to analyze % of students succeed exams. If I do so the output is series of multi indexes. But I need a dataframe from this as an output.

```
df.groupby(["school","class"]).passed_or_not.value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

Comment: so need `.reset_index()` ?

Comment: where on this current code?

Comment: to end of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(["school", "class"]).passed_or_not.value_counts(normalize=True)*100.reset_index(name='share')
```